# SpriteBatch.draw libgdx shows nothing

Tags: java, libgdx

I am trying to display a simple image in my program, but the function does not showing anything!
The Code with some comments speaks for itself:

```
public void draw(SpriteBatch batch, float parentAlpha){
    batch.draw(plane, this.getX(), this.getY(), this.getWidth()/2, this.getHeight()/2, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight(), 0, 0,
            this.getRotation(), 0 , 0, plane.getWidth(), plane.getHeight(), false, false); //shows nothing
    //batch.draw(texture, x, y, originX, originY, width, height, scaleX, scaleY, rotation, srcX, srcY, srcWidth, srcHeight, flipX, flipY)
    batch.draw(plane, this.getX(), this.getY()); //shows the image at x, y (0, 0)
    //batch.draw(texture, x, y)
}
```

I hope you understand my problem. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the issue is that you're passing `0` for `scaleX` and `scaleY`.
To draw the image at it's normal size, pass `1` instead.

Without any more information, this is the only thing that jumps out at me.

Comment: I tried and it did not change anything. This was not the solution :( but thanks anyway

Comment: @user1951516 There might be other issues, but I'm pretty sure you don't want to scale your image to `0`. At this point we'd just be guessing...update your question with some more information such as where this method is being called from, how you are setting up your viewport/creating your batch, etc. Although, the fact that your second `draw()` call works makes me think that the issue is with the arguments to the first call--what does `plane.getWidth/Height()` return?

Comment: plane.getWidth/height() returns 200. like it should. i debugged it. (Gdx.app.log) the method is called. if i set scale to 1, it does not change anything

Comment: My guess is that you're drawing the image outside of the viewport, but without more information I afraid I can't help anymore than that. Check out this [example](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/tests/gdx-tests/src/com/badlogic/gdx/tests/SpriteBatchTest.java) which demonstrates rotation/scaling.

Comment: I gave up. i did not find the solution and changed to 3d :) and 3d works like a charm :P (the beginning was hard, but now it's easy)